# Как float-элемент прижать к нижней границе родителя?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, float

Никак не могу прижать (оранжевый) `float` элемент с классом `.text`, 
к нижней границе (желтого) родителя с классом `.main`.

Пример:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: gray;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  float: left;
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.input-wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
<div class="text">
  <span>Телефон:</span>
</div>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="+7 926 987-65-43" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

С `float` это вряд ли получится сделать. Можно с `position: absolute` прижать к низу:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: gray;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 88px;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.input-wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
<div class="text">
  <span>Телефон:</span>
</div>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="+7 926 987-65-43" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант с `absolute` на всю высоту:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: gray;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 88px;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.input-wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
<div class="text">
  <span>Телефон:</span>
</div>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="+7 926 987-65-43" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[flex](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) :

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: gray;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.text {
  
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.input-wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
<div class="text">
  <span>Телефон:</span>
</div>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="+7 926 987-65-43" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант с `flex` на всю высоту:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: gray;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.text {
  
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.input-wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
<div class="text">
  <span>Телефон:</span>
</div>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="+7 926 987-65-43" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`table`:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: gray;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
}

.text {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.input-wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
<div class="text">
  <span>Телефон:</span>
</div>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="+7 926 987-65-43" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S: если я правильно понимаю задание.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте свойство `line-height`:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: gray;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  float: left;
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.input-wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
<div class="text">
  <span>Телефон:</span>
</div>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="+7 926 987-65-43" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет! 
Но, line-height распирает блок .text по высоте. 
Может существует еще какой-то способ (кроме flex-ов)?

Comment: @Rabbit можно абсолютно спозиционировать span по нижней границе .text, предварительно указав .text какую-то высоту.

Comment: Спасибо! 
Я понял, что в этой ситуации сделать резиновую высоту не удастся.

Answer (score -1):

```
.text {
  float: left;
  background: orange;
  /*margin-right: 10px;*/
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -11px;
}
```